# Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert doesn't work on Android 7.0 for datepicker

Tags: android

In my build.gradle following are the details:-

```html
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "org.package.test"
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.5"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
    }
```

I am using datepicker where I tried following code to change the style of datepicker to HOLO_DARK:-

```html
  datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog (getActivity(), AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK, this, year, month, day);
```

But I could see, in Android studio it was showing THEME_HOLO_DARK is deprecated and on my mobile Android 7.0 it was still showing default calendar look.

Then I tried following:-

```html
  datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog (getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert,this, year, month, day);
```

Still I got default calendar look.

I haven't tried this on other Android OS version, as I have all devices with 7.0.

Comment: Its working properly for me on  5.0 and 7.0. Try customizing the theme.
                Ex:-
 
`<style name="DialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#dd1</item>
    </style>`


-
`new DatePickerDialog(this, R.style.DialogStyle,null, 2010, 10, 05).show();`

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. I am creating datepicker with programming not XML.

Comment: yes.. go to your style.xml and add a custom theme. Then set that theme as your theme in java code